# Error:(25) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, src

The R. became red. I just add another class / activity and i got an error 
Error:(25) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in package 'com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs' and Error:(23, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout' with value '@layout/content_bodyache').
and [sample is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouHaY.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzlPA.png)Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

```
package com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
         */

             mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
             mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

        /**
         * Lets inflate the very first fragment
         * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
         */

             mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
             mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
        /**
         * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
         */

             mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                 String title = "";


                 // Inserting navigation
                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_sent) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new SentFragment()).commit();
                    title = "Emergency Hotline";

                 }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_inbox) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit(); //firstAid (health and life)
                    title = "First Aid and Survival Tips";
                }
                // [dito ipapasok ung sa map]
                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_draft) {
                     /*FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new MapFragment()).commit(); //firstAid (health and life)*/
                     title = "Locate Hospital";

                     Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
                     startActivity(i);
                 }

               /*  if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_map) {
                     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new MapFragment()).commit(); //firstAid (health and life)
                     title = "Locate";
                 }*/
                 return false;
            }

        });

        /**
         * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
         */

                android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name);

                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

                mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use:

```
android:srcCompat="@drawable/wallpaper"
```

Do some changes :

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/wallpaper"
```

as it (the `srcCompat` attribute) is actually defined within AppCompat library.

Important: you will need to add the appropriate namespace for this.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

What you are getting seems like it is just a lint error that can be ignored. I have tried and have the same error, but it is working correctly.

if it will not work you can try

```
android:src="@drawable/wallpaper"
```